# How can I add/compile multiple handlebar template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, partials, handlebars.java

I have a microservice running which reads handlebar from yml file. Right now I am working on partials where some part of my every template can be made common/re-used. Since I am reading handlebar template name from my yml file. It is one template name at a time. But how can I include/import/compile partial in Java.

Currently I am getting an error:
Partial xxx.hbs could not be found at xxx.hbs

Tried this solution:

```
TemplateLoader loader = new ClassPathTemplateLoader("/resources", 
".hbs");
Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars(loader);
Template template = handlebars.compile("greeting");
```

But I want to load a partial let say which is inside greeting.hbs.

Partial xxx.hbs could not be found at xxx.hbs

Comment: And... where is this greeting.hbs file located in yourproject? How do you build/run your project?

Comment: So here is explanation. I have 2 microservices running. Service A has all the templates greeting, xxx.hbs etc located in resources folder. It is Spring Spring Boot project. Service A passes these templates to Service B which has Handlebar code to generate the final json response. Now when Service B parses greetings handlbar template, it does not recognise xxx.hbs which is added as partial in greeting.hbs. Where should xxx.hbs should be located? Thanks. Let me know if any more clarification is needed.